# angularfire changes won't commit to database

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angularfire

I'm new to Angular and ionic3. 
I have managed to add user-specific items to my firebase database. But I am having issues with .remove() and .update(). My code runs smoothly with no error and all the console.log tests are printed and the toast messages are shown, but the changes I make won't show up in my database. both write and read has been set to true in my database rules. 
my item.model.ts looks like this:

```
export interface Item {
key?: string;
taxonid: number;
navn: string;
navn_vit: string;
kommentar?: string;
```

}

I use these methodes for update/remove

```
editItem(item: Item){
    console.log("test1");
    return this.itemRef.update(item.key, item);
}
removeItem(item: Item){
    console.log("test1");
    return this.itemRef.remove(item.key)
}
```

the ts code looks like this

```
removeItem(item: Item){
console.log("test 0");
this.obs.removeItem(item)
.then(() => {
    console.log("test 2");
    this.toast.show("${item.name} deleted");
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('mypage');
})
```

}

```
    saveItem(item: Item){
    console.log("test1");
    this.obs.editItem(item)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("test2");
        this.toast.show(`${item.navn} is changed`);
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('mypage');
    });
}
```

I have followed Paul Halliday's youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtKjv92L0ihAkTsq7-mxOGk8NrSXV7MY7) 
and my code is almost exactly like his, with the exception that the items are stored under the user that adds them.